# XML SQL query Output format issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

My SQL query is:

```
select MedicalHeightValue, MedicalWeightValue 
from TableA
```

My column names & values are:

```
MedicalHeightValue(67), MedicalWeightValue(220)
```

Output should be like:

```
<HealthAttribute>
   <Identifier>MedicalHeightValue</Identifier>
   <Value>67</Value>
</HealthAttribute>
<Healtttribute>
   <Identifier>MedicalWeightValue</Identifier>
   <Value>220</Value>
</HealthAttribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
;WITH CteData AS
(
    SELECT  
        'MedicalHeightValue' AS 'Identifier', MedicalHeightValue AS 'Value' 
    FROM dbo.TableA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
       'MedicalWeightValue' AS 'Identifier', MedicalWeightValue AS 'Value' 
    FROM dbo.TableA
)
SELECT *
FROM CteData
FOR XML PATH('HealthAttribute')
```

Comment: Here MedicalHeightValue ,MedicalweightValue both are column names. So both the column names should come between identifier as shown in format above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.Value, C.Identifier
from TableA
    outer apply (values
        ('MedicalHeightValue', MedicalHeightValue),
        ('MedicalWeightValue', MedicalWeightValue)
    ) as C(Identifier, Value)
for xml path('HealthAttribute')
```

you can also do this without explicitly specifying columns:

```
with cte(data) as (
    select * from TableA for xml path(''), type
), cte2 as(
    select
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Identifier
    from cte as c
        outer apply c.data.nodes('*') as T(C)
)
select *
from cte2
for xml path('HealthAttribute')
```

but I think it's a bit overkill for your task

Comment: Hi,I need another suggestion here. :

Comment: @Poornima what exactly do you need?